# Shell Script excuted fail in Linux at command

Tags: linux, shell-script, at

When I run a Linux "at" command,I find the user's shell script executed fail,
for example,I write the following code in my script

```
 #!/bin/csh  #or #!/bin/bash
 echo "Now will excute a shell script"
 dir=`pwd`
 my_path=`/home/Jim`
```

When I run the script in the command line, It's works fine.

While I run that using the "at" command,follwing message will be shown

Now will excute a shell script
dir=/home/Jim/Desktop:Command not found
my_path="/home/Jim":Command not found

I tried lots of times,but can still now work

So Please anybody can help me to fix this problem.Thank you & Regards!

Comment: how do you use at ?

Comment: bash and csh are "!=" , does your script really have both at the top? Is it a bash script, or a csh script? (Are single quotes & backticks the same in bash & csh?)

Comment: I means if using #!/bin/csh  or #!/bin/bash,the error info will both be shown.

Answer (score 1):

When you using backticks at the shell or in a script it attempts to execute the contents as if it was a program.

This line is trying to execute the program named `/home/Jim`, but I believe from what I can get out of your question, this is your home directory, not an executable program.  So what you almost certainly need to do is put the `/home/Jim` in quotes, not backticks (`).

```
my_path=`/home/Jim`
```

Comment: His error shows that `/home/Jim` is double quoted and it seems like whatever this `at` is, it runs `dir=/home/Jim/Desktop` and `my_path="/home/Jim"` as commands

Comment: Look closer at his error.  It is **Command not found**.  You don't get a **command not found** error when trying to save a string to a variable.   Unfortunately the OP's formatting question formatting was sorta messed up, so I can't say this with 100% certainty, but sure seems very likely to me that he has backticks instead of quotes.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I mean the `at` treated the whole lines as commands, as if `dir=/home/Jim/Desktop` and `my_path="/home/Jim"` are programs.

Comment: Oh, [at](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=at&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+8+jessie&format=html&locale=en) is a tool that lets you run your command at some later point in time.  Mostly people use cron instead, but `at` is still installed by default on lots of distros.  I was assuming the OP was just doing something like `echo "scriptpath" | at {time}`,  but maybe not.